# ¿Como puedo restar 2 valores separados como si fuera uno solo?

Tags: java

Para un curso de Java en linea me piden crear una funcion que regrese la diferencia entre un objeto "Money(euros,centavos)" y otro,y que si la diferencia es negativa que regrese un objeto con valores 0,asi como en este ejemplo:

```
Money a = new Money(10, 0);
Money b = new Money(3, 50);

Money c = a.minus(b);

System.out.println(a);  // 10.00e
System.out.println(b);  // 3.50e
System.out.println(c);  // 6.50e
```

Esto es lo que tengo del metodo hasta ahora:

```
 public Money minus(Money decreaser){

        if(this.lessThan(decreaser)){
              Money newMoney = new Money(0,0);
              return newMoney;
        } else{

            Money newMoney = new Money(this.euros - decreaser.euros,this.cents - decreaser.cents);
            return newMoney;
        }

    }
```

El problema es la segunda parte,como se puede ver esta manera de restar por separado los valores de euros y centavos no es correcta,ya que restando 10.00 - 7.50 me daria algo asi como 3.-50,le he estado dando vueltas y no se me ocurre una manera convincente de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero comprobas que si tenes menos centavos de los que queres restar y que tus euros sean mayor a 0 para "pedirle" 100 centavos. El caso que no se cumplan las 2 condiciones se hace una resta comun.

```
public Money minus (Money decreaser){
    if((this.centavos < decreaser.centavos)&&(this.euros > 0)){
        return new Money(this.euros - 1 - decreaser.euros, 100 + this.centavos - decreaser.centavos);
    }else{
        return new Money(this.euros - decreaser.euros, this.centavos - decreaser.centavos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta,me ayudaste a entender el porque se hacia la resta de esa manera,ademas estaba pensando hacer un IF con otras variables aparte aparte pero tu solucion me parece mucho mas limpia.

Comment: De nada Dan, cualquier otra duda realiza una pregunta. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Primero hacer un solo total:

```
double total1 = this.euros + this.cents / 100;
double total2 = decreaser.euros + decreaser.cents / 100;
```

Luego restar ambos totales:

```
double resultado = total1 -  total2;
```

Después sacar la parte entera y la decimal:

```
double entero = (int)resultado;

double decimal = (resultado - entero) * 100;
```

Crear nuevo objeto con parte entera y decimal

```
Money newMoney = new Money(entero,decimal);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta,se me habia olvidado que puedo hacer "conversiones" entre tipos de variable usando (nuevotipo)variable